# PDE as a system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

It has been said that a PDE is like an infinite dimensional system of ODEs. How can one see this by a clear example? Can any PDE be transformed into an infinite dimensional system of ODEs?

Comment: Search for "method of lines"

Comment: "It has been said": where exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a PDE with two independent variables $x$ and $y$ and dependent variable $u$.
You can approximate derivatives with respect to $x$ by difference quotients, e.g. 
$$ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} \approx \frac{u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)}{h}, \ \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \approx \dfrac{u(x+h,y) - 2 u(x,y) + u(x-h,y)}{h^2}$$
Then with $x_k = h k$ for integers $k$, the PDE becomes a system for the infinitely many dependent variables $u_k(y) = u(x_k, y)$.

Comment: But then the system will not necessarily be a system of ODEs?

Comment: If there are derivatives with respect to $y$, it will be.